# Can I run Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud on Sun sparc servers?

Tags: cloud, ubuntu-9.10, sparc, eucalyptus

I would like to deploy a private cloud using Ubuntu Server 9.10.  There is a -sparc iso available [here.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/9.10/release/ubuntu-9.10-server-sparc.iso)

My question is if any of the cloud packages included in 9.10 will work on sparc hardware?  A search for sparc on the Eucalyptus forums yields no results.

I realize that "commodity hardware" usually means x86 but sparc boxes are what I seem to have a excess of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypervisor LDom from SUN can be used on a SPARC architecture to run Solaris VMs.
As you may be aware, UEC (Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud) comes with Ubuntu server 9.10 and
Eucalyptus 1.6 built in. 
Eucalyptus right now supports Xen / KVM and even to an extent VMWare ESX as a Hypervisor.
You must check if Eucalyptus can be configured to have LDom as a hypervisor.